# Capybara - Finding active text on active tab

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, automated-tests

I'm using cucumber and capybara to build some basic tests to familiarise myself with automated testing.

What I am trying to do is check to see if a specific tab is active or not.

```
Then(/^I should see an active "(.*?)" tab$/) do |tabText|
```

My active tab just has a class of active added to it

```
ul.tabs li a.active
```

So essentially I need some way of checking if a 'ul.tabs li' of text 'tabText' has a class of 'active'.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the tag has the specific text. Something like that:

```
Then(/^I should see an active "(.*?)" tab$/) do |tabText|

  expect(page).to have_selector("ul.tabs li a.active", tabText)

end
```